# Identify list of tables which are updated, when Tag values are modified or inserted into Wonderware Historian server

Tags: sql-server, wonderware, historian

I would like to ask the following:

1. Identify the list of tables, which are updated when tag values are
   modified or new tag is inserted into the system.
2. What SQL query should I run to retrieve the list of updated tags including 
   their latest value, old value, updated time etc at any point in time?

Please let me know about it.

Comment: This all depends on your table structure. Do you have a time-stamp column, an identity property column? row_versioning? How about some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While tightly integrated with SQL Server, Wonderware Historian does not actually store the real-time tag data in SQL Server. Instead all tag data is stored in a proprietary file system. The data is expose within SQL Server as views via a proprietary OLE DB provider.
The following pdf will give a better understanding of the WW Historian architecture:

http://iom.invensys.com/EN/SoftwareGCC14Presentations/Wonderware/WW%20INFO-07%20Valuable%20Information%20From%20WSP%202014%20R2.pdf

The following pdf will provide more detail as to what features and functions that is supported by the OLE-DB provider, this includes query options, versioning etc.:

https://www.logic-control.com/datasheets/1/Historian/HistorianConcepts.pdf
With regards to retrieving the latest values for each of the tags you can query the “Live” table / view.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to  SQLdependency which

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read documentation and see Live view. Similarly, I have looked tables such as Modlogtable and Modlogcolumn, but I am not sure whether they fulfill my purpose as stated below and also as mentioned in documentation  they decrease the performance of database server.
My goal is to create SQLdependency which help me to find the tags whose values have been modified at particular time. This dependency only work on tables not on views. So is there any table which can tell me when tags are updated or when data  is received ?

Comment: @MuhammadHammad Are you looking to see changes in configuration (new tags added or removed) or are you trying to subscribe to changes in the in existing tag values?

Comment: I am looking solutions for both, specially changes in the  existing tag values

Comment: @MuhammadHammad - Unfortunately, I don’t believe what you want is possible out of the box via WW Historian OLE DB provider. I suspect your best bet would be to implement a lazy thread in your app that periodically check the timestamp of each tag in the runtime table and compare it to a cached copy you hold in memory to detect if changes have occurred since the last scan. Be careful though query to many tags to fast will have server performance impacts on the Historian and your application.

Comment: @EdmondQuinton: The links are broken, can you please update with the new link or add search keywords to your answer.